# Save multidimensional array using Laravel and ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, forms

I am building a pharmacy management system. I have a condition where I need to build a section [image]

As shown in the picture, I need to store the data where the upper three should be same for all of the rows inputted below.
The form data is submitted as in the below picture.

[image]

But the data when looped and saved is not being saved as desired. Only the last row of the data is being inserted and I am also confused to store supplier, purchase date and note since these data should be repeated as many as the number of rows are added.

**PurchaseController.php**

```
public function storePurchase(PurchaseStoreRequest $request)
{
   
    $purchase = new Purchase();

    $count = count($request->name);

    // return response()->json($request->all());

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

        $purchase->supplier = $request->supplier;
        $purchase->purchase_date =  $request->purchase_date;
        $purchase->description = $request->description;

        $purchase->category = $request->category[$i];
        $purchase->name = $request->name[$i];
        $purchase->generic_name = $request->generic_name[$i];
        $purchase->batch_number = $request->batch_number[$i];
        $purchase->company = $request->company[$i];
        $purchase->strength = $request->strength[$i];
        $purchase->expiry_date = $request->expiry_date[$i];
        $purchase->quantity = $request->quantity[$i];
        $purchase->selling_price = $request->selling_price[$i];
        $purchase->purchase_price = $request->purchase_price[$i];

        $purchase->save();

    }

    return response()->json(['message'  =>  'Purchase Saved Successfully']);
}
```

Can someone help me to store these three fields in the database repeating the number of rows submitted ?
Currently only the last row is being inserted into the database.

Comment: `$purchase = new Purchase();` write this line inside the loop, you did it outside. Thats whay only last low inserted. Anyway, its will `$purchase = new Purchase;`

Comment: have you tried `array_merge_recursive()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every loop, you need to create a new instance, then It will create a new record on each loop :

```
public function storePurchase(PurchaseStoreRequest $request)
{
    // $purchase = new Purchase();

    $count = count($request->name);

    // return response()->json($request->all());
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $purchase = new Purchase();  // create new instance end with (); on each loop
        $purchase->supplier = $request->supplier;
        $purchase->purchase_date =  $request->purchase_date;
        $purchase->description = $request->description;
        $purchase->category = $request->category[$i];
        $purchase->name = $request->name[$i];
        $purchase->generic_name = $request->generic_name[$i];
        $purchase->batch_number = $request->batch_number[$i];
        $purchase->company = $request->company[$i];
        $purchase->strength = $request->strength[$i];
        $purchase->expiry_date = $request->expiry_date[$i];
        $purchase->quantity = $request->quantity[$i];
        $purchase->selling_price = $request->selling_price[$i];
        $purchase->purchase_price = $request->purchase_price[$i];
        $purchase->save();
    }
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Purchase Saved Successfully']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was wondering why the data was not submitted. And just pushing that line inside did the trick.

Comment: Can you share me any idea to store total of the purchase without having another table to do so?
I mean total of every rows (Quantity * CP)

Comment: Do you want to store Quantity * CP on another table?

Answer (score 1):

This might be an another way to accomplish what you're looking for.

```
$sharedKeys = ['supplier', 'purchase_date', 'description'];
$sharedData = $request->only($sharedKeys);

$multiKeys = ['category', 'name', 'generic_name', 'batch_number', 'company', 'strength', 'expiry_date', 'quantity', 'selling_price', 'purchase_price'];
$multiData = $request->only($multiKeys);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->name); $i++) {
    $individualData = array_combine($multiKeys, array_column($multiData, $i));

    Purchase::create($sharedData + $individualData);
}
```